# Merging two CSV files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two CSV files.Columns names are like below example

```
CSV1 
SAMAccountName mail
JohnS          johns@example.com

CSV2
GivenName Surname DisplayName Department Title Mail MobilePhone Manager
```

What I've wanted to do is to compare the CSV1 with CSV2 and match the mail column in CSV2 file with SAMAccountName Column in CSV1 and export a new CSV which gives the below output

```
CSV3(merged.csv) as in script
GivenName Surname DisplayName Department Title Mail MobilePhone Manager SAMAccountName
```

I tried the below powershell script which i found in stack overflow site posted sometime back and i never got the values from the SAMAccountName column of CSV1.All other column names are coming up without any issue but SAMAccountName column is blank.I'm not a powershell script expert need some help here.Below is the example script i used.

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\CSV1.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\CSV2.csv

ForEach($Record in $csv2){
$MatchedValue = (Compare-Object $csv1 $Record -Property "SAMAccountName" -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru).value
$Record = Add-Member -InputObject $Record -Type NoteProperty -Name "SAMAccountName" -Value $MatchedValue
}
$csv2|Export-Csv 'C:\temp\merged.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-csv .\test2.csv |Update-Object -On Mail (Import-csv .\test1.csv) |Export-csv .\test3.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common, You can do this quite easily using:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\CSV1.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\CSV2.csv'

$csv3 = foreach ($record in $csv2) {
    $matchingRecord = $csv1 | Where-Object { $_.mail -eq $record.mail }
    # if your goal is to ONLY export records with a matching email address,
    # uncomment the if ($matchingRecord) condition

    #if ($matchingRecord) {
        $record | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {$matchingRecord.SamAccountName}}
    #}
}

$csv3 | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\merged.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```